# Problems with fstream reads ok but not write user input string

Tags: c++, fstream

I cannot find the problem in my code. `readFile` function works well, but `writeFile` function does not make any changes in the file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
const int BUF_SIZE = 1024;

void readFile(fstream &file, char buffer[BUF_SIZE]);
void writeFile(fstream &file);

void readFile(fstream &file, char buffer[BUF_SIZE])
{
    int position;
    cout << "Please enter a position to read from the file some info" << endl;
    cin >> position;
    file.seekg(position, ios::beg);
    file.read((char*) buffer, BUF_SIZE); // <<<<<

    for(int i = 0; i < file.gcount(); i++){
        cout << buffer[i];
    }
}

void writeFile(fstream &file)
{
    char temp[100] = "HHHH";
    //cout << "Please enter some info to add to the file" << endl;
    file.write((char*) &temp, 100);
    for(int i = 0; i < file.gcount(); i++){
        cout << temp[i];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];

    if (argc != 2){
        cout << "Program usage: prog_name file_name";
        return 1;
    }

    fstream file(argv[1], ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);
    if (!file){
        cout << "File can not open or doesn't exist";
        return 1;
    }

    //Try to read & write some info from/to file in particular position

    readFile(file, buffer);
    writeFile(file);

    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

When I create a new `ostream` it works well, but I want to understand why `fstream` in/out mode works in my code only for reading.

Comment: How do you know that `writeFIle` does not make any changes?

Comment: By the way (and unrelated to your problem) but `(char*) &temp` is *wrong*. Either use just `temp` or use `&temp[0]` (no casting needed in either case).

Comment: Using `gcount` in `writeFile` makes no sense: it's the number of characters last *read* from the file.

Comment: I know that cause there are no any changes when I open the target file, if I  create new ostream it works well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see several problems:

1. The reason behind the writing problem is probably because you reach the end of the file (is the file smaller than `BUF_SIZE` bytes?). This sets the EOF bit, which makes any write operations to fail. You have to clear that bit before (use the `std::fstream::clear` method):

   ```
   void readFile(fstream &file, char buffer[BUF_SIZE])
   {
       int position;
       cout << "Please enter a position to read from the file some info" << endl;
       cin >> position;
       file.seekg(position, ios::beg);
       file.read(buffer, BUF_SIZE);

       for(int i = 0; i < file.gcount(); i++){
           cout << buffer[i];
       }

       file.clear(); // clears EOF
   }
   ```
2. The line `file.write((char*) &temp, 100);` is wrong since you are actually passing a point to the `temp` variable, which is also a pointer, but it is camouflaged by the cast. These ones are OK: `file.write(temp, 100);` or  `file.write(&temp[0], 100);`
3. When printing the written characters, you are using `std::fstream::gcount`, which literally means *get count* (amount of characters read in the last get operation). You are writing (*put*) not reading (*get*). Indeed, you are actually indicating how many bytes you are willing to write, so use it:

   ```
   file.write(temp, 100);
   for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
       cout << temp[i];
   }
   ```
4. Finally, you are *always* writing 100 characters, probably including some garbage from the buffer. As I see that you want to let the user choose what to write (the commented line), you can instead:

   ```
   const size_t size = strlen(temp);
   file.write(temp, size);
   for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++){
       cout << temp[i];
   }
   ```

In addition, some suggestions:

1. Use a `std::string` to read the user input, in this way you avoid a possible buffer overflow (if the user enters more than 100 characters).

   ```
   cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // read the link bel
   string temp;
   getline(cin, temp); // need #include <string>
   file.write(temp.c_str(), temp.size());
   ```

   You will probably want to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21567292/1485885) to learn more about the first line (basically it avoids the `getline` to be skipped after using `cin >> position`).
2. Avoid the for loop to print the user input. For both the buffer and the `std::string` options you can just `cout << temp << endl;`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, cause Im in process of studying. 
1. Can you clarify what operation set EOF bit? istream.read? I thought that there are two independent pointers - one for read and another for write operations (as seekp and seekg) is it not right think?

Comment: Yes, `stream::read`; although pointers are independent the state of the file is shared and checked by both `read` and `write`.

Comment: 2. Ok! Some programmer dude told me about this in comments too
3. Ok!
4. All of other recomendation is about using string type, and I find it more useful here too, THNX

Best regards
Anton

Comment: **"the state of the file is shared and checked by both read and write"**this is the real answer for my question

Comment: NOTE!: 
1. 'file.write(temp, 100);' does not work in gcc, use only 'file.write(&temp[0], 100);' variant
2. 'const size_t size = strlen(temp);' does not work too, use 'const size_t STR_SIZE = temp.size();' [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313263/error-cannot-convert-const-string-to-const-char-for-argument-1-to-size-t-strle)

Comment: @Anton, correct, I checked it only for VS, and in the case of the second variant, of course, if you switched to `std::string` obviously the `strlen` won't work anymore (actually, the second example already uses it, but wasn't commented: `file.write(temp.c_str(), temp.size());`). Thanks for pointing these out!